# Eclipse is not opening

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to java and eclipse. I even saw this type of query on this website. But I have applied all those methods and it was also helpful. But when I try to open eclipse, it is not opening:
This is my path for java

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6

this is where my eclipse is

> C:\Users\New folder\eclipse

But when I run the eclipse I'm getting an error

> "A java rumtime environment(JRE) or java development kit(JDK) must be
>   available in order to run eclipse. No java virtual machine was found
>   after searching the following location: C:\Users\New
>   folder\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe javaw.exe in your current path"

Please tell me the possible solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have java installed on your Computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed jdk then Eclipse won't have any issue to start. I think you just have installed JRE to run java programs. You need to install JDK.

To check whether you have installed JDK. Check Path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java`. Your Java directory should contain directory `jdk1.6..`, If you don't have this directory there, search it at other places. If you did not find directory then you didn't install JDK.

Download JDK from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should set JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME variable. http://www.javawebonline.com/java-se-programming/beginners/java_home-jre_home-environment-variables/

And another suggestion is you should move your java home to another location and test your path to java such as

> C:\Java\jre6

instead of

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6.

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Users\New folder\eclipse
Open **eclipse.ini** file with text editor and add the javaw location there
( right after -vm part ) like so:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_33/bin/javaw.exe <--- change to your path
-vmargs
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the command prompt by pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Type `javac` and check the output.

If it gives all the options and usage, then you have configured the PATH vairables correctly, or else you have not set them up correctly.

Try it by checking the value at the command prompt.

#### NOTE

You need to open a new command prompt each time you change the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two `Program Files` folder in your `C: drive`

such as

```
C:\Program Files

C:\Program Files (x86)
```

then try to put your java inside

```
C:\Program Files
```

instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are running 64 bit eclipse in 64 bit operating system. If you are running 64 bit eclipse then you need 64 bit JDK. Please install 64 bit JDK and run eclipse.